# После переустановки Centos на выделенном сервере OS перестала запускаться

Tags: сервер, centos

После переустановки Centos на выделенном сервере операционная система перестала запускаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, с чем может быть связана такая проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не видит DHCP. сервер

Comment: Если OS была переустановлена на этом конкретном сервере, и нормальной ситуации он загружается не по сети, то похоже что на сервере потерян boot record, с которого должен загрузится grub. Я бы посоветовал еще раз переустановить OS, следуя всем правилавилам установщика.

Comment: Переустановка OS не помогает. Что потерял DHCP я понял, не знаю как исправить. Centos просто не стартует. Пробовал ставить в разные конфигурациях, от Minimal до GUI server